# Blutooth not working on Thinkpad E570 with Realtek chip

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, thinkpad, realtek

Hi I experienced the same problems with Realtek wifi drivers as other users, and I solved this problem following the steps described here:
[Wifi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wifi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570)
I needed to update to kernel 4.15 though.

However! I still experience problems with bluetooth - the Blueman bluetooth manager can be run, but says there is no bluetooth device in the PC.

Any suggestions?