# No Wifi conection in HP Pavilion x360 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Realtek RTL8821CE)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp, realtek-wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, at the moment of the installation it didn't ask me for a WiFi connection, and it hasn't worked since then.

Here are some of the commands I have used.

Code:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for jenn: 
*-network UNCLAIMED       
     description: Network controller
     product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
     vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
     version: 00
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1000000-a100ffff
$ lspci | grep Wireless
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe 
Network Adapter

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
01:00.0 Network controller : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

$ dmesg | grep iwl
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
01:00.0  Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless  Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless  Network Adapter [103c:831a]

$ lspci -nn -d 10ec:
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
$ uname -a
Linux jenn 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The network appears unclaimed.

I have seen other cases in which this commands output other options, but in my case, there is only that one.

Finally, there are no additional drivers, even though I am connected with memory that gives me internet.
[image: .]

I'm new in Linux distribution, so I'm really lost with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images! Please add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3`, post  as plain text into your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll edit it right now.

Comment: Also please post the kernel version `uname -a`.

Comment: Did you tried this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1071334/790920 ?

Comment: Yes, this one resolved my problem! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071334/790920), the problem could be solved:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x *.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
reboot
```