# "WiFi adapter unplugged" Ubuntu 18.04 rtl8821ce

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I'm 14 years old and I am completely new to Ubuntu and in general to Linux.

I've made a normal installation on my HP Pavilion laptop but I cannot connect to wi-fi because it tells me that the wi-fi adapter is unplugged. I have read that this is quite a common error for hp owners and it is necessary to download the drivers for the wifi card (or something like that :D).

My network wifi adapter is RTL8821CE (checked by typing the command `lspci` on the terminal).

In order to solve this problem I have been told to type these commands sequentially:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms git build-essential
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
cd /libfirmware/rtlwifi
sudo wget https://git.karnel.org/pub/smc/linux/karnel/gitfirmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtlwifi/rtl8821cefw.bin
```

It goes all good for the first 5 inputs, but when it comes to typing the last line it gives me this error:

```
--2018-12-13 16:41:35--  https://git.karnel.org/pub/smc/linux/karnel/gitfirmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtlwifi/rtl8821cefw.bin
Resolving git.karnel.org (git.karnel.org)... 68.178.213.61
Connecting to git.karnel.org (git.karnel.org)|68.178.213.61|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I've been fighting with this all week so I'd appreciate some advice.

Comment: i have also tryed to use "curl -LO" instead of "sudo wget" but it tells me "Failed to connect to git.karnel.org port 443: Connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means a secure connection cannot be established with that address. 
The driver you're looking for doesn't seem to exist in the official Ubuntu repository. However, here's a potential solution:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1071334/896137)

The first line assures that kernel utilities and headers are up to date. 
You then fetch the working kernel with `git clone` (you might have to run `sudo apt-get install git` beforehand). 
After the repository living at "https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce" is copied (i.e. cloned) onto your computer, you Change Directory to the  "rtl8821ce" folder (`cd rtl8821ce`).

"chmod" allows you to change permission (mode) for a given file, making it executable (+x). Finally, `./dkms-install.sh` executes the file. 
Keep in mind that you might want to keep the script somewhere, in case you wish to uninstall the driver (say you want to update it). 
However, in case you where to lose it, you can clone the same repo(sitory) , chmod and run `./dkms-remove.sh` as mentioned here https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

Good luck on your new journey!

Answer (score 0):

The URL is wrong.It seems like  https://git.karnel.org should be  **https://git.kernel.org**

wget is command to download, instead you can open the URL in browser and search for the mentioned driver from the site and then download manually.

Good Luck!