# HP 14-cf1015cl trying to find drivers / get WiFi and touchpad working on dual boot

Tags: drivers, hp

On the HP 14-cf1015cl laptop, I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS dual booting with Windows 10.

When running Ubuntu, the trackpad and WiFi do not work.

Attempt #1: Using Ubuntu software and updates to look for "Additional Drivers." I made sure proprietary drivers were downloadable on the "Ubuntu Software" tab. The "Additional Drivers" tab says that no additional drivers are available and that no proprietary drivers are in use.

Attempt #2: I tried to install the drivers from HP. On their website they only  have drivers for Windows. I talked to HP support chat and got this response: 
"[MyName], we do not have drivers for Ubuntu. We have a level 2 team for it. At this stage we would recommend you to contact HP Smart Friend Services who will be able to further assist you against a nominal charge, which can either be one time or a subscription. You can call them at (844) 814-1800 and share your case number 5026938009; they will take it from there." I did eventually get to premium service (see part 4).

Attempt #3: I called costco concierge (I bought the laptop from costco), who got me to the premium HP service without charge.

Part #4: HP support directed me to the Ubuntu commercial support number (this one: https://www.ubuntu.com/support, 737-204-0291), where I did leave a message but don't expect a return call since I don't have a subscription to their corporate support.

From the first comment:

alina@alina-HP-Laptop-2019:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0113] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
alina@alina-HP-Laptop-2019:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

From here I found my way to this related post: [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) and will be looking into this solution for the WiFi. Here's a step-by-step answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1082204/921247 . <- This solution did not work for the WiFi. Here's the error message I got:

About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:

cleaning build area...

'make' -j4 KVER=4.15.0-29-generic...(bad exit status: 2)

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108 not found

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-29-generic (x86_64)

Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/build/make.log for more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:

cleaning build area...

'make' -j4 KVER=4.15.0-29-generic...(bad exit status: 2)

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108 not found

Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-29-generic (x86_64)

Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108/build/make.log for more information.

Finished running dkms install steps.

Comment: I would recommend [edit]ing the question and make it a question about one issue and post the other as a separate question. For the Wi-Fi part, please run the following command in Terminal and add the output to begin with: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Comment: @pomsky

~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821] 

Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]

 04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0113] (rev 01) Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:0001] Kernel driver in use: nvme

 :~$ rfkill list 0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no

Comment: @pomsky

From here I found my way to this related post: How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04? and will be looking into this solution for the WiFi.

Comment: It should work, also there's another question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce

Comment: When trying to install this fix, I get the error message above.