# Problems installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo V145-15AST

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

EDIT: Some new information: the boot process is very slow when the PC is plugged in (electrically) but not when it is running on the battery...

EDIT: Just to make it clear, I'm only asking about one issue, but I mention the previously resolved issues in case they are relevant.

I installed 18.04 on a new Lenovo V145-15AST. The first startup was fast, but unfortunately neither the touchpad nor the wifi were working. For the wifi I found a fix in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce) and the touchpad is also fixed (I upgraded to a newer mainline kernel 4.20.0).

Upon restarting the computer however, the boot now takes a huge amount of time (over a minute).

Here are the first errors which pop up upon startup:

```
Mär 10 12:05:45 Lenny kernel: input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:24/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
Mär 10 12:05:45 Lenny kernel: ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
Mär 10 12:05:45 Lenny kernel: ACPI: More than one Lid device found!
Mär 10 12:05:45 Lenny kernel: button: probe of PNP0C0D:01 failed with error -17
```

(this is not exactly what I see but these are the lines recovered from `journalctl -b`) Then the boot process goes on by saying it did not find the lvmtab and is going to scan for devices.

here is the output of the `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 4.896s (firmware) + 3.612s (loader) + 34.859s (kernel) + 11.984s (userspace) = 55.351s
graphical.target reached after 11.971s in userspace
```

And here is the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
      6.348s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.023s postfix@-.service
      1.652s dev-mapper-xubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
       746ms lvm2-pvscan@8:2.service
       656ms udisks2.service
       483ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       463ms apparmor.service
       419ms systemd-rfkill.service
       412ms ModemManager.service
       401ms accounts-daemon.service
       397ms NetworkManager.service
       367ms plymouth-read-write.service
       318ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       315ms lightdm.service
       265ms snapd.service
       251ms upower.service
       243ms apport.service
       232ms rsyslog.service
       229ms bluetooth.service
       221ms systemd-logind.service
       218ms keyboard-setup.service
       215ms virtualbox.service
       192ms speech-dispatcher.service
       192ms wpa_supplicant.service
       161ms systemd-journald.service
       152ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       149ms alsa-restore.service
       145ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       142ms systemd-resolved.service
       125ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       110ms lm-sensors.service
       108ms grub-common.service
       104ms lvm2-monitor.service
       100ms gpu-manager.service
        98ms systemd-udevd.service
        87ms avahi-daemon.service
        85ms pppd-dns.service
        81ms thermald.service
        73ms user@1000.service
        71ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        62ms polkit.service
        59ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F325\x2d0DFE.service
        58ms systemd-modules-load.service
        55ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        53ms snapd.seeded.service
        53ms dev-mqueue.mount
        51ms ufw.service
        51ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        50ms kerneloops.service
        50ms dev-hugepages.mount
        49ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        45ms blk-availability.service
        44ms systemd-random-seed.service
        42ms sys-kernel-config.mount
        41ms hddtemp.service
        31ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        31ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
        29ms console-setup.service
        23ms systemd-sysctl.service
        22ms plymouth-start.service
        20ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        17ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        17ms boot-efi.mount
        17ms dev-mapper-xubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dswap_1.swap
        16ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        12ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
        10ms ureadahead-stop.service
         9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         9ms systemd-backlight@backlight:amdgpu_bl0.service
         6ms setvtrgb.service
         5ms rtkit-daemon.service
         1ms snapd.socket
```

Here is also a (severely) truncated  output of `dmesg`:

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.20.0-042000-generic (kernel@tangerine) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-12ubuntu1)) #201812232030 SMP Mon Dec 24 01:32:58 UTC 2018
    [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.20.0-042000-generic root=/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000087fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000088000-0x00000000000bffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000e6fbefff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e6fbf000-0x00000000e71befff] type 20
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e71bf000-0x00000000e78befff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e78bf000-0x00000000e7bbefff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e7bbf000-0x00000000e7bfefff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e7bff000-0x00000000e7bfffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e7c00000-0x00000000e7ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0100000-0x00000000f01fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec10000-0x00000000fec10fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed80000-0x00000000fed80fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ff800000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000111ffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000112000000-0x0000000116ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.50 by INSYDE Corp.
[    0.000000] efi:  ACPI 2.0=0xe7bfe014  SMBIOS=0xe726f000  SMBIOS 3.0=0xe726d000  ESRT=0xe7270998  MEMATTR=0xe50da018 
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: LENOVO 81MT/LNVNB161216, BIOS 8ZCN21WW(V2.00) 10/04/2018
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2295.849 MHz processor
[    0.018032] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.018034] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.018042] last_pfn = 0x112000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.018049] MTRR default type: uncachable
[    0.018050] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
[    0.018052]   00000-9FFFF write-back
[    0.018053]   A0000-BFFFF uncachable
[    0.018055]   C0000-FFFFF write-through
[    0.018056] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
[    0.018058]   0 base 000000000000 mask FFFF80000000 write-back
[    0.018059]   1 base 000080000000 mask FFFFC0000000 write-back
[    0.018060]   2 base 0000C0000000 mask FFFFE0000000 write-back
[    0.018062]   3 base 0000E0000000 mask FFFFF8000000 write-back
[    0.018063]   4 base 0000FF800000 mask FFFFFF800000 write-protect
[    0.018064]   5 disabled
[    0.018064]   6 disabled
[    0.018065]   7 disabled
[    0.018066] TOM2: 0000000117000000 aka 4464M
[    0.018451] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
[    0.018617] last_pfn = 0xe7c00 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.025346] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x00000000e7270998 to 0x00000000e72709d0.
[    0.025362] check: Scanning 1 areas for low memory corruption
[    0.025367] Base memory trampoline at [(____ptrval____)] 26000 size 24576
[    0.025371] Using GB pages for direct mapping
[    0.025374] BRK [0x7bc01000, 0x7bc01fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025377] BRK [0x7bc02000, 0x7bc02fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025379] BRK [0x7bc03000, 0x7bc03fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025425] BRK [0x7bc04000, 0x7bc04fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025427] BRK [0x7bc05000, 0x7bc05fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025553] BRK [0x7bc06000, 0x7bc06fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025595] BRK [0x7bc07000, 0x7bc07fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025651] BRK [0x7bc08000, 0x7bc08fff] PGTABLE
[    0.025835] Secure boot could not be determined
[    0.025837] RAMDISK: [mem 0x334c1000-0x35a57fff]
[    0.025848] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.025853] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000E7BFE014 000024 (v02 LENOVO)
[...]
[    0.025939] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000E7BDA000 000038 (v01 LENOVO CB-01    00000001 ACPI 00040000)
[    0.025951] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.026111] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.026112] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000111ffffff]
[    0.026123] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x111fd5000-0x111ffffff]
[    0.026454] Zone ranges:
[    0.026456]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.026457]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.026459]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000111ffffff]
[    0.026460]   Device   empty
[    0.026461] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.026464] Early memory node ranges
[    0.026465]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000087fff]
[    0.026466]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000e6fbefff]
[    0.026467]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000e7bff000-0x00000000e7bfffff]
[    0.026467]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x0000000111ffffff]
[    0.026546] Zeroed struct page in unavailable ranges: 4281 pages
[    0.026548] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000111ffffff]
[    0.026550] On node 0 totalpages: 1019719
[    0.026551]   DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
[    0.026552]   DMA zone: 1134 pages reserved
[    0.026553]   DMA zone: 3975 pages, LIFO batch:0
[    0.027333]   DMA32 zone: 14719 pages used for memmap
[    0.027335]   DMA32 zone: 942016 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.054767]   Normal zone: 1152 pages used for memmap
[    0.054768]   Normal zone: 73728 pages, LIFO batch:15
[    0.057482] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408
[    0.057485] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
[    0.057495] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x00] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.057496] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.057497] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.057498] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.057508] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 4, version 33, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.057512] IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 5, version 33, address 0xfec01000, GSI 24-55
[    0.057514] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.057516] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 low level)
[    0.057518] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.
[    0.057519] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.
[    0.057521] Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.057523] ACPI: HPET id: 0x10228210 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.057532] ACPI: SPCR: SPCR table version 1
[    0.057533] ACPI: SPCR: console: uart,io,0x3f8,115200
[    0.057537] smpboot: Allowing 4 CPUs, 2 hotplug CPUs
[    0.057563] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[...] 
[    0.057582] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff800000-0xffffffff]
[    0.057584] [mem 0xe8000000-0xf00fffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.057586] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.057591] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.057606] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x97/0x52c with crng_init=0
[    0.057616] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:4 nr_cpu_ids:4 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.058550] percpu: Embedded 46 pages/cpu @(____ptrval____) s151552 r8192 d28672 u524288
[    0.058559] pcpu-alloc: s151552 r8192 d28672 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.058560] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 
[    0.058597] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1002650
[    0.058598] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.058601] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.20.0-042000-generic root=/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[    0.079933] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.079935] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
[    0.103780] Memory: 3833072K/4078876K available (14341K kernel code, 2319K rwdata, 4360K rodata, 2464K init, 5332K bss, 245804K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.104070] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.104081] ftrace: allocating 41332 entries in 162 pages
[    0.130165] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.130169] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.130171]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.130172] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.130173] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.134090] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 1000, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.134315] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.134324] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.134354] ACPI: Core revision 20181003
[    0.134660] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484873504 ns
[    0.134677] hpet clockevent registered
[    0.134684] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.163031] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.182682] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2117e3f45d7, max_idle_ns: 440795238761 ns
[    0.182701] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 4591.69 BogoMIPS (lpj=9183396)
[    0.182704] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.186785] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.186789] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.186822] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.188227] Dentry cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[    0.188963] Inode-cache hash table entries: 262144 (order: 9, 2097152 bytes)
[    0.189018] Mount-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.189043] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[...]
[    0.251265] pci 0000:00:02.4:   bridge window [mem 0xf0000000-0xf00fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.252547] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.252667] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.252763] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.252880] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.252988] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.253076] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.253163] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.253252] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 5 6 10 11) *0, disabled.
[    0.254058] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.254058] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.254058] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPC0.EC0_: GPE=0x3, EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.254058] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPC0.EC0_: Used as boot DSDT EC to handle transactions and events
[    0.254063] pci 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.254063] pci 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.254063] pci 0000:00:01.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.254063] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.254063] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.254709] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.254709] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.254709] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.254709] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.254709] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.254709] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.254709] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.254709] PTP clock support registered
[    0.254709] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.254731] Registered efivars operations
[    0.274855] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.276739] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
[    0.276804] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x00088000-0x0008ffff]
[    0.276806] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xe6fbf000-0xe7ffffff]
[    0.276808] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0xe7c00000-0xe7ffffff]
[    0.276809] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x112000000-0x113ffffff]
[    0.276809] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.276809] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.276809] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.276809] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.278727] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
[    0.278732] hpet0: 3 comparators, 32-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
[    0.280773] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
[    0.299508] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.299535] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.299729] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.299779] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.300108] system 00:00: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec01fff] could not be reserved
[    0.300110] system 00:00: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] has been reserved
[    0.300113] system 00:00: [mem 0xf0100000-0xf01fffff] has been reserved
[    0.300121] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.300316] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.300358] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs FUJ7401 PNP0303 (active)
[...]
[    0.328875] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    0.328944] Unpacking initramfs...
[    1.041823] Freeing initrd memory: 38492K
[    1.041870] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[    1.042105] pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.042107] pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: not connected
[    1.042373] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:01.0 to group 0
[    1.042387] iommu: Using direct mapping for device 0000:00:01.0
[    1.042404] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:01.1 to group 0
[    1.042463] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:02.0 to group 1
[    1.042486] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:02.2 to group 1
[    1.042505] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:02.4 to group 1
[    1.042591] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:03.0 to group 2
[    1.042687] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:08.0 to group 3
[    1.042781] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:09.0 to group 4
[    1.042799] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:09.2 to group 4
[    1.042889] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:10.0 to group 5
[    1.042973] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:11.0 to group 6
[    1.043068] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:12.0 to group 7
[    1.043171] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:14.0 to group 8
[    1.043190] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:14.3 to group 8
[    1.043311] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.0 to group 9
[    1.043331] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.1 to group 9
[    1.043349] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.2 to group 9
[    1.043371] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.3 to group 9
[    1.043389] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.4 to group 9
[    1.043407] iommu: Adding device 0000:00:18.5 to group 9
[    1.043426] iommu: Adding device 0000:01:00.0 to group 1
[    1.043446] iommu: Adding device 0000:02:00.0 to group 1
[    1.044165] AMD-Vi: Found IOMMU at 0000:00:00.2 cap 0x40
[    1.044167] AMD-Vi: Extended features (0x37ef22294ada):
[    1.044168]  PPR NX GT IA GA PC GA_vAPIC
[    1.044172] AMD-Vi: Interrupt remapping enabled
[    1.044172] AMD-Vi: virtual APIC enabled
[    1.044395] AMD-Vi: Lazy IO/TLB flushing enabled
[    1.046033] LVT offset 0 assigned for vector 0x400
[    1.046074] perf: AMD IBS detected (0x000007ff)
[    1.046083] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #0 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[    1.046177] check: Scanning for low memory corruption every 60 seconds
[    1.048530] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.048561] Key type blacklist registered
[    1.048638] workingset: timestamp_bits=36 max_order=20 bucket_order=0
[    1.050600] zbud: loaded
[    1.051222] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    1.051515] fuse init (API version 7.28)
[    1.106387] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.106390] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.106420] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 243)
[    1.106497] io scheduler noop registered
[    1.106498] io scheduler deadline registered
[    1.106568] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    1.107531] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    1.107606] efifb: probing for efifb
[    1.107637] efifb: framebuffer at 0xe8000000, using 4224k, total 4224k
[    1.107638] efifb: mode is 1366x768x32, linelength=5632, pages=1
[    1.107638] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    1.107640] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    1.109985] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[    1.112144] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    1.112551] ACPI: AC Adapter [ACAD] (on-line)
[    1.112629] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:24/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.112638] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.112652] ACPI: More than one Lid device found!
[    1.112680] button: probe of PNP0C0D:01 failed with error -17
[    1.112714] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
[    1.112735] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.112776] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[...]
[    2.235155] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (2 bytes read)
[   34.778476] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   34.946439] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   34.963380] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   34.965686] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <Lenny>.
[   36.111997] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   36.112029] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   36.112230] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   36.112402] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   36.112424] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[...]
[   43.111014] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[   43.111043] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [APCL]:
[   43.111045]   Local0: 000000000b8a5043 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[   43.111056] No Arguments are initialized for method [APCL]
[   43.111061] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[   43.111113] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[   43.111137] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[   52.194989] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[   52.195021] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [APCL]:
[   52.195023]   Local0: 00000000baf4ae88 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[   52.195035] No Arguments are initialized for method [APCL]
[   52.195042] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[   52.195293] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[   52.195648] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  354.259758] random: crng init done
[  354.259763] random: 5 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[  354.963670] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  354.963685] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  354.963696] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  363.024903] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[  363.024936] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [APCL]:
[  363.024938]   Local0: 000000007af5d42f <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[  363.024950] No Arguments are initialized for method [APCL]
[  363.024956] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  363.024977] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  363.025036] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  375.743443] RTW: WARN [TXFOVW]
[  ....] 
[  470.110438] RTW: WARN [TXFOVW]
[  513.384725] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[  513.384748] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [APCL]:
[  513.384749]   Local0: 00000000e21d59c6 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[  513.384758] No Arguments are initialized for method [APCL]
[  513.384760] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  513.384772] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  513.384781] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  514.881337] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[  514.881366] 
               Initialized Local Variables for Method [APCL]:
[  514.881368]   Local0: 000000006f7451c1 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[  514.881379] No Arguments are initialized for method [APCL]
[  514.881384] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.APCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  514.881403] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0.PCLK, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  514.881453] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  517.929462] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[  517.929495] 
[...]
[  609.116928] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0._Q1D, AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psparse-516)
[  624.127084] RTW: WARN [TXFOVW]
[ ...] 
[  625.247268] RTW: WARN [TXFOVW]
[  659.294240] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_PR.C002.PPCV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20181003/psargs-330)
[  659.294273]
```

Comment: Please ask about one issue at a time. Touchpad, Wi-Fi and slow boot are different issues.

Comment: I'm not asking about touchpad and wifi: these issues are fixed. I just mentionned these issue as they might be relevant to the rest of the topic. So at the moment, I'm just asking about the slow boot (which happened after I fixed the other two issues)

Comment: Try to boot with `acpi=off` boot parameter. And upgrade BIOS to the latest.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the indications. There is no BIOS update availiable for Linux (only windows 10) and the PC does not boot with acpi=off (it defaults to a limited shell)

Comment: BIOS is not for Windows or Linux. If there is only Windows utility then you'll have to flash it from Windows.

Comment: I know, but as you mention, the utility is only for windows. So I need to download a trial version of windows 10 to update the BIOS? Or is it reasonable to risk using Wine?

Comment: Wine won't do it.

Comment: @Pilot6 The Bios update did not change anything.

Comment: Small update: the release upgrade to 19.04 (as well as following the instruction of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04 to install the wifi driver) solved the problem.