# How do I fix 'No wifi adapter found' issue (RTL8821CE)?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently Installed Ubuntu 19.04, with Windows as dual boot.
My device is Lenovo ideapad 330-15AST U.
I can't connect to the wireless networks. 
I am an absolute beginner to Ubuntu.

Ran the following command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

Following is the received output:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [17aa:3861]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) && https://askubuntu.com/q/990378/480481

Comment: @pomsky The solution worked! Yesterday, I had squandered an entire day running random commands from internet. Finally, this worked. My heartfelt gratitude. Thank you very much!