# Wifi rtl8821ce driver stopped working on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless

I was using ubuntu 19.10 and I had to install this Wi-Fi driver following instructions:

[How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

However after an update applied and restart it just stopped working

I searched on additional drivers and this was disabled

I tried to re-enable it but nothing happened

How can I make them work back?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by uninstalling the driver and installing the official Ubuntu package.

First, I uninstalled the old driver:

```
cd rtl8821ce/
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh
```

Then downloaded the driver to my phone: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/all/rtl8821ce-dkms/download

Moved it via USB to my laptop.

Installed it with dpkg:

```
dpkg -i rtl8821ce-dkms_5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

And finally rebooted the laptop.

Comment: This worked for me for Bionic too (and the other solutions of make-ing it from the Git repo did not, for some reason).

Comment: Though I had been using the drivers from an independent Github repository, they stopped working in validated mode at the end of July, 2020. *Thank you* for pointing out the new "genuine" (shall I say cannonical?) driver!