# Wifi rtl8821ce driver stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, ideapad

I have a Lenovo 320 laptop with rtl8821ce wifi adapter. I was using Ubuntu 19.04 and the adapter worked after following 
[these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce/1071336#1071336).

I upgraded to 19.10 and the wifi is not working now.

The output of `lshw -C network` is as follows

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:16:45:45:5c:35
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a2104000-a2104fff memory:a2100000-a2103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2000000-a200ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: b0:fc:36:38:c0:d0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.52 multicast=yes
```

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183908/wifi-rtl8821ce-driver-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-19-10/1183973#1183973?newreg=c66bc64cd4b248c7968b028756ce8a35) had the same problem as me -including installing the driver from additional drivers- but following the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Is there anything else I can do?

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: wl, 8821ce, rtl8821ce
```

```
$ sudo dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

```
$ sudo modprobe rtl8821ce && dmesg | grep rtl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8821ce': Device or resource busy
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `sudo dkms status` and finally: `sudo modprobe rtl8821ce && dmesg | grep rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: May we also see: `lsmod | grep 8821` and: `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Is there any chance that you may have installed two different 8821ce drivers at the same time? One manual install, or one Additional Drivers install, and one dkms install? Note: Kernel modules: wl, 8821ce, rtl8821ce

Comment: @heynnema yeah, addtional drivers was installed first, then i installed the driver manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/all/rtl8821ce-dkms/download.
didn't work.
i set additional drivers to 'Don't use the device' and installed the deb manually again, still nothing works ,and additional drivers is set again to first option, apparently the two are the same thing.

Comment: Lets remove the extra dkms driver... `sudo ./dkms-remove.sh` from the original source folder, or `sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425 -k all` then `dkms status` should not show the driver, then show me `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` again. Then check Additional Drivers again.

Comment: Any reason to have the bcmwl dkms driver installed?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `modinfo 8821ce | grep filename`

Comment: I've got a lead on a new 8821ce driver that works. We first need to remove all double-installed drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

```
$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Uninstall your current dkms driver (https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)...

```
cd rtl8821ce          # old source folder
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh # uninstall old dkms driver
dkms status
```

Now we make sure that duplicate 8821ce drivers have been removed...

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 | grep modules
```

If you need a different driver, try this one... https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce. (git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git). Don't follow the ReadMe there for how to install it, rather, follow the same procedure that you did before, so that you get the dkms install.

```
git clone https://github.com/shubham151/rtl8821ce.git # git clone new driver
cd rtl8821ce             # new source folder
chmod +x dkms-install.sh # make executable
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh  # make executable
sudo ./dkms-install.sh   # install new dkms driver
```

**Update #1:**

- uninstalled bcmwl dkms module
- uninstalled rtl8821ce dkms module
- reinstalled rtl8821ce from .deb file

Comment: i ran `sudo ./dkms-remove.sh` -actually i did that before multiple times!- 
the result is 
`About to run dkms removal steps...
Error! There are no instances of module: rtl8821ce
v5.2.5_1.26055.20180108.1 located in the DKMS tree.
Finished running dkms removal steps.`

Comment: but `dkms status` still returns
`bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: and `sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 | grep modules` returned
`Kernel modules: wl, 8821ce, rtl8`

Comment: i ran `sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425  --all`  and now `dkms status` returns `bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: tried to install the driver deb  again and restart, still nothing.
so i uninstalled it.

Comment: `sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 | grep modules` now returns `Kernel modules: wl, 8821ce`

Comment: @ahmedgalal  Good job! Now we have to find the other 8821ce module. `sudo locate -b 8821ce`. Also, why do you need the bcmwl dkms module? Do you have a broadcom comm device on your system?

Comment: i removed the broadcom module using `sudo dkms remove bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom --all` , then installed the driver deb again , and it is now working !!
apparently the broadcom device was the one that added this 8821ce modules, because after removing it  running `sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 | grep modules` was returning nothing.
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: and i probably added the broadcom driver by mistake while searching for solutions.

Comment: @ahmedgalal does `dkms status` now show `rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed` again?

Comment: basically yes, just a minor difference in versions:
`rtl8821ce, 5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425, 5.3.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed
`

Comment: @ahmedgalal that looks like the same version that I was asking about. Glad it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

For recent ubuntu 20.04 LTS this should do the trick:

```
apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```