# Realtek WiFi Adapter Not Found after 19.10 upgrade

Tags: wireless, upgrade, realtek-wireless, 19.10

When I installed Ubuntu 19.04, the Realtek RTL8821CE WiFi adapter on enp2s0 was not found.

Result of `sudo lshw -C network`:

[image: Result of sudo lshw -C network]

I tried to install several different versions but the problem was still there. I stayed with 19.04 and some guy installed the `rtl8821ce driver` and somehow managed to make it work.

Result of `sudo lsmod`:

[image: Result of sudo lsmod]

I eventually upgraded to 19.10 and a couple of days after, then out of nowhere when I turned on the laptop I had no WiFi adapter again.

I tried reinstalling the `dkms` again but nothing worked. Tried 100 things online but nothing worked.

Here's another instance of `sudo lsmod`:

[image: Here's another instance of sudo lsmod]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to AskUbuntu,

So, you could maybe install the driver rtl8821ce by following the procedure described here: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html#ID10 and https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

Start by installing all packages required for the installation of the driver

`sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms`

Then: 
`git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git`

Move to the directory: `cd rtl8821ce`

And install the driver: `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. Just tried it again and nothing...