# WiFi/Wireless is not working

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and cannot use WiFi on Ubuntu. Every single answer requires an install, and if it’s an apt-get or Linux command, I can’t use it. If there is a website to download a `.gz` file or something for Ubuntu, but I don’t have to be on Ubuntu to download, that would be great.

Output of `lspci -kin | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

First line ^

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: How do we know what to download? The is no generic "WiFi diver".

Comment: @Pilot6 Okay pilot6

Comment: @Pilot6 Done pilot

Comment: You can temporarily connect to the internet using your android phone and use https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: @Pilot6 I use iPhone, so I don’t know if I can use that

Comment: i don't know if iphone has USB modem feature. Mybe someone has an android for a couple of minutes?

Comment: @Pilot6 Do you mean Hotspot?

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, This works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use USB tethering.

1. Connect your phone to PC with Ubuntu.
2. Go to **Settings -> More -> USB tethering** (If you have Android device)

or on iPhone, go to **Settings -> Personal Hotspot** as seen below

[image: iphone settings]

Comment: Thanks Gryu! I used your solution and am now downloading the  drivers for my PC

Comment: On iPhone, (for some data plans) go to settings -> Personal hotspot. Do the instructions to use WiFi on Ubuntu for iPhone.