# Realtek RTL8221ce Wireless driver / adapter [Answered]

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.04, realtek

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.04, and it says I have no WiFi adapter connected, and will not allow me to connect to wireless internet. I have seen many places that this may be because Ubuntu hasn't released a driver supported with Ubuntu, for Realtek drivers, but I feel like there is a way to get it to work for RTL8821ce. My Ubuntu 19.04 is running along side Windows 10 Home (Build 19.09), as I would like to keep Windows too. An answer would be greatly appreciated, as I've tried many methods in the terminal, and nothing has worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I have tried this method, and failed. I think the main issue using that article is, I'm running 19.04. I know this doesn't change much from commands in .04 versions, but I have tried this method a few times, and it failed each time.

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, does the Realtek adapter appear if you boot from an 18.04 LiveUSB?

Comment: The tomaspinho version 'makes' perfectly on my 19.10 system. In what way did it fail for you? Is there any clue in /var/log/dkms/...make.log?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Comment: I have tried the one above. It too does not work.

Comment: If I try to boot into 18.04 it comes up errors. I'm currently running 19.04, and it does list it when I input: lspci into the terminal. But it won't read it to where I can connect wireless.

Comment: As for the tomaspinho installation, It worked as it should, then I had to restart my PC for the changes to take place, and when I had restarted it, there was still no adapter found.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, **tomaspinho's driver is not working on Kernel version 5.3**; check yours:

```
~$ uname -a
```

In any case, this driver is, according to its [README.md](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce), "*being developed for Arch Linux and Ubuntu 18.10. No support will be provided for other Linux distributions or Linux Kernel versions outside of that range*". I wouldn't recommend this driver for 18.10 users either, since there is a better solution:

## Solution

Try the new driver available in the ubuntu repos. For this, **[first unistall tomaspinho's](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)** and then do:

```
# Perform the following AFTER UNINSTALLING tomaspinho's driver
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

**This solution may only work in Ubuntu 19.10**. Consider ditching the 19.04 version in favor of the 19.10.

Working for me in an ASUS fx505dy-bq024 with the Realtek RTL8821CE wifi card under Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: If I were to ditch 19.04, how do I upgrade to 19.10? I have 19.04 installed and to overwrite it, is there a way I can do it straight from 19.04? I dont really want to have to uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall it.

Comment: You can upgrade via the _Software Updater_. Go to _Software & Updates_ and open the "Updates" tab. For "Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version", select "for any new version". Now run _Software Updater_ and the upgrade to 19.10 will be available. You should know that support for Ubuntu 19.04 will finish this month, in that it is worth the upgrade to 19.10. Neither of them are _Long Term Support_ versions (LTS), the next being due this April. Also, it is a good idea to be comfortable installing and uninstalling your distro for many (and good) reasons.

Comment: I upgraded Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10, and the wireless driver now works! Thank you for your help, and the issue has now been resolved.

Comment: Hi @BeTheBestGOAT , in order to close the question, don't change the original title, click on the [tick that you will find next to the answer](https://postimg.cc/hJ42z7fW). Best wishes for you and your Ubuntu!

Comment: @ÁlvaroF.LópezdeQuadros how do you sign this so secure boot can be enabled? I have a related question - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240517/signing-dkms-module-automatically-enabled-in-ubuntu-20-04