# Signing dkms module automatically enabled in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, additional-drivers

On Ubuntu 20.04 the driver for the realtek wireless card I need is listed under `additional drivers` in settings. I enabled this driver which is a dkms module, but I can only get this to load on disabling secure boot authentication in mokutils. How do I get the signature of this module that was built automatically, and add it to the configuration so I can enable secure boot? There's this gist - https://gist.github.com/dop3j0e/2a9e2dddca982c4f679552fc1ebb18df for signing when building from source, I am not sure how to adjust this for the the setup here.

Answer (score 0):

### Installation

1. Create a directory under `/root`, say `/root/module-signing`, put the three scripts below in there and make them executable: `chmod u+x one-time-setup sign-modules dkms-sign-module`
2. Run one-time-setup
3. Reboot your computer to deploy the MOK
4. For each module you will want to sign via DKMS, create a file `/etc/dkms/<module_name>.conf` with the following content:
   `POST_BUILD=../../../../../../root/module-signing/dkms-sign-module`

The awkward relative pathname is important since DKMS prepends its own path to it, so an absolute path will not work.

### What's missing in the Installation instructions

---

Here are more details for each step in the instructions.

#### Step 1. How to put the three scripts in `/root/module-signing`:

```
sudo mkdir /root/modules-signing
cd /root/modules-signing
sudo -H gedit one-time-setup
sudo -H gedit sign-modules
sudo -H gedit dkms-sign-module
```

Each time you run gedit copy and paste from the github page into gedit's window. Then use 'Save' option and quit.

#### Step 2. Run one-time-setup

```
cd /root/modules-signing
sudo ./one-time-setup
```

#### Step 4. `<module_name>` setup

To get this to actually work, substitute `<module_name>` with the name of your RTL module.

If you run into difficulties post comment(s) below.