# Wireless connection issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, realtek-wireless

Just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Lenovo Yoga 530.

I am having issues with my network, it's unrecognised.

```
*network UNCLAIMED 
  description: Network controller
  product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) and https://askubuntu.com/q/990378/480481

Answer (score 0):

`UNCLAIMED` means Ubuntu is recognizing the hardware, but it needs a driver for it to work. Thanks this card is really common and there is a driver on Github for it.

You will need an ethernet connection and follow this steps on your terminal:

```
sudo su
apt install -y dkms git
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
./dkms-install.sh
modprobe 8821ce
```

After completing that steps, you should be good to go, and your card should be working.