# Cannot install wifi driver RTL8821cd and no access to ethernet

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

I just installed ubuntu, but I have no access to internet. The laptop I installed it on has no ethernet port and the wifi adapter seems to not have the proper drivers installed.

The Network controller included in this laptop is RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

I have searched for solutions and all the solutions seem to have access to internet on their ubuntu device.

Comment: You can plug in a android phone with usb and enable usb tethering to get internet

Comment: You probably will need an internet connection on *some* device to obtain the drivers you need.  If you get stuck some place in particular please keep your question up-to-date with edit.

Comment: @MaxSilvester I didn't realize this was a thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) but the Wifi Driver for the Realtek RTL8821CE is NOT in the official Ubuntu Repositories. So without an internet connection you need to obtain it using another internet enabled PC and copy the file to your laptop.