# WiFi is disabled and not able to turn it on in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, wireless, iwlwifi

```
    deshiyan@aspkv:~$ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 5c:ba:ef:13:1a:2f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:56 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7800000-f780ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: bc:e9:2f:fd:aa:60
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:49 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7704000-f7704fff memory:f7700000-f7703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp4s0f3u3
       serial: ee:22:5e:46:3e:f1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC Ethernet Device ip=192.168.225.23 link=yes multicast=yes
```

This is the message and the first one is disable.

Comment: What does `rfkill list` tell you?

Comment: rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 0):

I had a different wifi driver but I think this is the same problem. I solved it by following the direction in the following link [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

You can also check if there is the source code for your driver so you install it by yourself.

Cheers!

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you check that you downloaded the proper wifi device driver for you wifi device model? Also, did you made sure you turned off the secure boot option from the bios settings? These are some of the basic prerequisites for this solution to actually work.