# No wifi adapter found on lenovo ideapad 330

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, lenovo

Yesterday, I updated ubuntu, before that my wifi was working properly, but after updating it is showing no wifi adapter found. When I first installed ubuntu on my laptop it had same problem but I fixed it following the steps given in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ) video. But this time it is not working. If anybody could help me out it would be wonderful

edit-
-> output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: rtw_8821ce, wl, 8821ce
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38a8]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6, I disabled it but it is still not working

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms` ?

Comment: @Raffles, I installed it and restarted the laptop but still no success

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) and the answer it links to can help.