# Can someone help me with getting my network driver to work? I have no experience and am using Linux as a last resort because my HDD crashed

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a Realtek RTL8821CE and when i try to use the apt download command, it can't find any of the necessary files. I'm sorry if this is unclear, I'm new here and I'm new to all of this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: For best help provided details as to your OS & release help. That is the starting point, details we currently don't know. Ubuntu LTS releases provide two hardware stacks (chosen at install time by the ISO you use to install, but can be changed). We currently have no idea what you're running.