# Wifi adapter not found and i dont have ethernet port

Tags: networking, wireless, adapter

I have HP Pavilion x360 - 14m-dh0001dx and i recently installed ubuntu 20.04 lts. And my wifi is not showing. Ps my laptop doesn't have a built in ethernet port. Any solutions?

the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
 DeviceName: WLAN
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install a wireless driver. Connect your laptop to the internet using e.g. a phone by a USB cable, then tun in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Then reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: This was a  useless comment. Did everything install without errors?

Comment: yes, i did everything and no errors were found

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled in BIOS?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `dkms status` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` commands.