# wifi not working on fresh ubuntu 22.04 installation

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, realtek

linux kernel - 5.15.0-37-generic
ubuntu 22.04
inxi -Nazy:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A modules: rtw88_8822ce pcie: gen: 1
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:c822
    class-ID: 0280
  Device-2: Realtek 802.11ac WLAN Adapter type: USB driver: btusb
    bus-ID: 1-10:5 chip-ID: 0bda:b00c class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

What I've tried:

[How to install Wi-Fi driver for Realtek RTL8821CE on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04)

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiv9P-j9a_4AhV1R2wGHRfSAu8QFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Finstalling-realtek-rtl8821ce-driver-to-use-the-wireless-network-interface-in-ubuntu%2F&usg=AOvVaw2KZvMj-eakKJ60i6-3euG8

there seems to be a network adapter on the official ubuntu website: https://ubuntu.com/certified/component/753

but I don't know how to install this network adapter. I'm currently asking this using usb tethering with mobile data.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

Comment: And disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: @Pilot6 It shows no additional drivers available for some reason

Comment: the official Ubuntu website shows it as pre-installed and should work automatically. Can you paste output from `sudo lsmod`?

Comment: It is useless to install any 8821ce driver when you have an 8822ce device. They are not the same. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep rtw88`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
After updating linux firmware, reinstalling Linux, Windows I finally discover that there are two factors which cause it:

1. **Windows Hibernate**
2. **Windows fast startup**

With Windows fast startup turned off and Windows shutdowned (not hibernated, sleeped etc.) I have Wifi on Linux.
Windows has to block the wifi adapter when not shut down completely.

I hope this will help you get it running !

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect using an ethernet cable or some other method, you can share wifi using the bluetooth of your cellular device, try running the command

`sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms --reinstall`

This worked for me on my Hp 14s laptop. Hope this helps!