# Wi-Fi not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

- I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my Lenovo laptop.
- It does not show up the WiFi options.
- I tried downloading the drivers and installing them in the way as described here [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce#990571). But nothing in use.
- Whenever i try to use `make` command, I get

  ```
  /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
  (standard_in) 1: syntax error
  make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-39-generic/build M=/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
  make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
  arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
  ./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
  ./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 27: gcc: command not found
  make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  /bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
  (standard_in) 1: syntax error
   CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o
  /bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
  scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target 
  '/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
   make[2]: *** [/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
   Makefile:1551: recipe for target '_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
   make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
   Makefile:1902: recipe for target 'modules' failed
   make: *** [modules] Error 2
  ```

**EDIT 1**

- After installing build-essential also the problem exists with the error.

  ```
  make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-39-generic/build M=/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
  make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
  Makefile:975: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
    CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o
  cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
  scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target 
  '/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
  Makefile:1551: recipe for target 
  '_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
  make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-39-generic'
  Makefile:1902: recipe for target 'modules' failed
  make: *** [modules] Error 2
  ```

**EDIT 2**
 - I have upgraded my kernel to 4.18.6 and also installed `libelf-dev`. Again when I enter `make` command. It gives

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.6-041806-generic/build M=/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.6-041806-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1325:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:317: recipe for target '/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
Makefile:1504: recipe for target '_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bee/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.6-041806-generic'
Makefile:1902: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: The make command reports gcc is missing. If you want to compile the driver, install `build-essential` package.

Comment: Before going further, are you sure you have the exact same device? Even same models can come with different WiFi cards (and other parts, of course).

Comment: I suggest that you: `sudo apt install libelf-dev` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `build-essentials` package. Use the command

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential
```