# No wifi connection or ethernet port on laptop

Tags: wireless

I'm currently running the Kubuntu 18.10 and I have this issue with my laptop where I can't get my computer to detect my wifi chip.

My current wifi chip is a Realtek 8821CE wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
and my laptop has NO ethernet ports so I can't figure out which drivers to install and how to install them.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/990571/894044

Comment: That tutorial does not apply to my issue as the driver recommended is useless in my scenario

Comment: You can follow that tutorial. It is for rtl8821ce rtl is for realtek and 8821ce is your modal number.