# Wi-Fi Card Not Being Identified in Lenovo ThinkPad E570

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, realtek, realtek-wireless

Obligatory I'm completely new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, and I've run into the same problem everybody does when first starting - my WiFi isn't working. I tried following this question which had been asked already for the same model laptop: [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce) , however all I got was a bunch of errors instead:

```
error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
.ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
```

And then after trying to do the "sudo make install" function, I get:

```
install -p -m 644 8821ce.ko /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8821ce.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:1908: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 and I have access to an Ethernet cable, however I would greatly like to have my WiFi card working. What can I do?

Edit:
I should also mention that the hardware details (as viewed from windows) is:

Realtek 8822BE Wireless LAN 802.11ac

Actually thinking of it now, is that the same driver as in that link I posted above? That was an 8821ce, but if that's supposed to be the same code then that explains why mine wasn't working. Would I have to download something else for an 8822BE?

**Edit**
Running
`lspci | grep -i real` returns:

`04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822`
`05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)`

If it helps, I've noticed that when booting back into Windows that the wifi is initially shown as being off, before switching itself back on

Comment: Does `lspci | grep -i real` show b821 or c821?

Comment: Added what it returns to bottom of original post

Comment: That is the rtl8822be then

Comment: Try the source in the staging area of 18.04 /usr/src/linux-4.15.0/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/rtl8822be/ or maybe try 18.10 to see if it got it into the normal repositories.

Comment: Sorry but I got no idea what source in the staging area is, do you have a link to a page about it or something like that? Also if I don't have to I was kinda hoping to stick to 18.04 because of the longevity, I'm going to be using it for the next four years or so whereas 18.10 support runs out sometime this year right?

Comment: Does `lsmod | grep cfg` show r8822be in results?

Comment: I get `cfg80211                622592    1   mac80211`