# Wifi doesn't work on Lenovo ideapad-130-15IKB

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

After installing ubuntu 18.08 LTS along side with windows 10 , i encountered some problems using ubuntu the first is the touchpad but thanks to askubuntu i corrected the problem.
Now i'm searching solutions to another problem that is with my wifi wireless connection it doesn't work and more over when entering to wifi settings i see an `No Wifi Adapter Found' i already tried some stuff but unluckily not working.
when typing`sudo lshw -C network` i get this :

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 98:29:a6:67:23:2b
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b110ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: 22:2e:f7:46:24:ff
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.91 link=yes multicast=yes
```

When typing `lspci -knn | grep Net -A02:00.0  i get :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: wl
```

When trying `rfkill list` i get :

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Help please i want back my wireless connection

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: try:
sudo modprobe 8821ce
if not working then try this
https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce

Comment: @Pilot6 i deed what you've requested

Comment: @Pilot6 any help please !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently got a laptop with that wifi card. Tried several guides and drivers to make it work. The easiest way (and best in my opinion, as there is a driver version around the web with a bug which after you disconnect from a network and then reconnect, it fails, you have to disable and enable wifi to be able to connect again) is to download and install the driver from this deb package:
https://launchpad.net/~wenchien/+archive/ubuntu/rtl8821c/+files/oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms_0.8_amd64.deb
Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1740231
You will need an active internet connection to install the driver, since it will pull some packages from the Ubuntu repos.

Edit:

My apologies. You will need an active internet connection until the wifi driver is installed (ethernet cable or, if you have bluetooth, you can share from your phone or tablet connected to wifi). Instructions are for a 64bit machine. Open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
```

This will fetch available packages in the repositories, but it will not update your system, you can do that later after fixing the wifi issue.

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/~wenchien/+archive/ubuntu/rtl8821c/+files/oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms_0.8_amd64.deb"
```

This downloads the driver in form of a .deb package from a PPA.

```
sudo apt install ./oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms_0.8_amd64.deb
```

Installs the downloaded driver, downloading the required package dependencies first.

```
exit
```

Reboot and, after login, you should be able to see, connect and disconnect from available wifi networks. Hope that helps

Comment: Don't know if it works, but it would be a good idea to add the exact steps to the answer, as the OP might not know what to do with .deb packages. It might be a good idea to add [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wenchien/+archive/ubuntu/rtl8821c) properly to get updates, when available.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mikewhatever i will try it and answer if it has succeeded

Comment: and now both my bluetooth and wifi are not working

Comment: I am sorry it didn't, but why tell me? The answer was posted by whocanobi.

Comment: Sorry i don't really know. When i go to settings i see the same probleme 'no wifi adapter found' help please

Comment: @mikewhatever i posted this question and it was marked as duplicate. I entered to see the answers here  , i tried what was written but nothing works

Comment: @whocanibi thanks for your help , but the solutions that you've proposed didn't work for me  , you have something else to propose  , it will be very helpful ; thanks a lot

Comment: @SaidOugouadfel I'd advise elaborating on what exactly did not work. For example, if there is an error in any of the steps, post both the step and error. "Nothing works" doesn't give us anything useful to work with.

Comment: @mikewhatever i assure you that all the steps were executed correctly.

Comment: when typing the last commend 'sudo apt install ./oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms_0.8_amd64.deb ' i get :

Comment: Note, selecting 'oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms' instead of './oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms_0.8_amd64.deb'
oem-wifi-realtek-8821ce-lp1767920-4.15-dkms is already the newest version (0.8).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Does the problem come from my kernel version because i did upgrade it

Comment: @mikewhatever my current kernel version is : 4.20.10-042010-generic

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever i've corrected the problem thanks.

Comment: this does not work for me try - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPfLVsyQU_A, this worked for me. I am using lenovo ideapad 130 15ikb.