# Lenovo 18.04 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found

Tags: networking

I know this question has been asked here before, but the answers haven't helped me.  I have a Lenovo Ideapad on which I've installed via UNetbootin 18.04.  Everything else with the install went smoothly, but like others my wifi is not working.  In particular, I've gotten the `no wi-fi adapter found` message.

Many of the fixes relied on gaining access to the internet via an ethernet connection, but my machine doesn't have a connection for that.

I haven't used Ubuntu in several years so my Linux foo is very rusty. I'm essentially a newbie.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]:  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
          Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:co24]
```

Let me emphasize newbie again.  I don't know how else to post this.  Here's the feedback now that I attempt to run `make` after updating and upgrading again:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/build M=/home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:155: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 27: gcc: command not found
Makefile:970: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
/home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce/Makefile:2157: home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce/hal/phydm/phydm.mk: No such file or directory
/home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce/Makefile:2166: home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk'.  Stop.
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/john/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic'
Makefile:2237: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
john@john-Lenovo-ideapad-130S-11IGM:~/Downloads/rtl8821ce$ sudo make install
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
install -p -m 644 8821ce.ko  /lib/modules/4.18.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat '8821ce.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile:2243: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Ran the commands and got these errors:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
john@john-Lenovo-ideapad-130S-11IGM:~$ sudo apt-get install libelf-dev
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run the command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you.  See above.  Also, since I posted this, I re-installed 18.04 this time I ticked the box choosing 3rd party and propietary software, which didn't fix the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Here is the method to install the driver *with* a temporary internet connection by, for instance, tethering from your phone. https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce If this is an impossibility, I will write a lengthy answer as to the procedure without an internet connection. Do you still have the USB or DVD from which you installed Ubuntu? Many of the prerequisites are on it.

Comment: I do still have the usb drive I used.  I'll try to tether to my phone first

Comment: Rats.  Tethering is not working.  I'm still not connected.

Comment: It will take me some minutes to write the answer. I will post the first part so you can get started then I will edit to add more.

Comment: Oh!  I got it to connect via bluetooth somehow. Sorry for the premature post

Comment: If you are connected, then I will have to edit my answer severely. Please stand by...

Comment: OK.  I was following directions you gave in the above linked answer.  It's still downloading, though.  So, I'll wait

Comment: I think I'm done! Please double-check that you've taken the most recent steps in my answer below. Post any errors.

Comment: Will do.  My little computer is working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh   
sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Revision 31 July, 2019 9:40 am EDT

Comment: Working through it.  Thank you!

Comment: Everything went great until I typed 'make' after editing the file.  I got the message

Command 'make' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install make
sudo apt install make-guile

I tried each of those commands and was told that those could not be located.

Comment: Just realized I'm no longer tethered.

Comment: connected again, but same problem.

Comment: Re-tethered.  Did another apt-get update and upgrade.  Now getting this:

Comment: See above in my original post.  I can't get make to work stil

Comment: You *must* install make, gcc, etc. using: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential` Please do so and try again. You will also need: `sudo apt-get install libelf-dev`

Comment: OK.  Did the first two, but not the third.  Will do all 3.  Thank you!

Comment: Errors are copied above in my original post.  Thank you for sticking with me.

Comment: Unable to get dpkg lock simply means that another process, typically Update Manager is active. Please wait 5-10 minutes and try again. Update Manager runs in the background and pops up a window to say that updates are available and asks if you'd like to install them. The only way it can do this is to start the process in the background.

Comment: I believe that the steps I outlined above will not work at all. I have found another process that I've tested on an 18.04.1 VM and I will edit the answer above to outline it.

Comment: OK.  Yeah.  I tried what you added this morning and it didn't work.  It was unable to locate the package(s) at tomaspino.  I'll wait and try again and also wait for your next suggestion.  Again, thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the internet. Once you are connected, git clone should work well.

Comment: So, I upgraded successfully to 19.04 yesterday and tried the above with the same result.    The error message read E:  Unsupported file ./dkms-install.sh given on commandline

Comment: Please confirm that dkms is installed: `sudo dpkg -s dkms` Also, is the file executable? `ls -al dkms-install.sh` It ought to report -rwxr-xr-x where 'x' means 'executable.'

Comment: dkms is not installed.

Comment: Please retrace the steps above. *All* of the prerequisites are required. After you install them all, including dkms, try again.

Comment: Success!  I don't know why it worked this time or why it didn't before, but...THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.

Comment: Done.  Thank you, again, chili!

Comment: Its really really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Pre-requisites:

1. The command 'lspci' shows the wireless card as RTL8821CE
2. You have a successful internet connection through USB thetering

I had a similar problem with my newly purchased Lenovo-V145-15AST, as Ubuntu did not find an active WiFi adapter after installing Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

As the wireless card was not found during Ubuntu installation, updates and upgrades were not performed during the installation. It seems that this prevented the successful installation of the driver for the RTL8821CE wireless card when I followed the advice of various posts on this issue.

What worked for me, provided that the command lspci does indeed list the wireless card, and that one has managed to theter via smartphone-USB, was the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git
```

as suggested in the second answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901922/error-showing-in-the-installation-of-git-in-ubuntu-18-04-2lts

Then followed this to the letter:
https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

After rebooting, the wireless card was up and connecting to my WiFi.