# Unable to use my wifi adapter in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, bluetooth, 19.04

Machine: [Asus TUF FX505DY](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DY/specifications/) (AMD Ryzen 5 3550H, 16GB, AMD Radeon RX 560X) ([manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/GamingNB/FX505DY/BG14684_FX505DY_FX705DY_A.pdf)).

I first live booted to see whether Ubuntu 19.04 ran OK. I realised my [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8821CE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04) WiFi adapter did not appear, but when I used the `lspci` command, the name of my wifi adapter was present.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h(Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:01.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15db
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15dc
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
```

`00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee`

```
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] `Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/560] (rev e5)
**02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE `802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
04:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
04:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
04:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
04:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
04:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
05:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

I have to constantly plug in an external WiFi adapter to connect this machine to the internet. This consumes an entire USB port on my I/O.

Comment: @Jeremy31 I don't think that driver will successfully compile in 19.04.

Comment: This is the method I suggest although it isn't yet confirmed and accepted so I can't  yet mark as a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162223/lenovo-18-04-no-wi-fi-adapter-found/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071299/how-to-install-wi-fi-driver-for-realtek-rtl8821ce-on-ubuntu-18-04 actually has an answer which worked. Me, I replace  Realtek cards with Intel cards so I don't have to play with drivers.

Comment: Upvoted and Voted to close as dupe.  **@chili555  :-)**