# Follow up question to "Lenovo 18.04 No Wifi Adapter Found"

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I am posting a follow up question to the below linked question:

[Lenovo 18.04 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162223/lenovo-18-04-no-wi-fi-adapter-found)

After reading the comments it seems that the advice works...for someone who has a wifi connection, which I cannot establish. So I was wondering if I could perhaps get chili555 or a similarly kind and knowledgeable soul to continue writing the advice for how to get the missing files when no wifi or hard wired connection can be established?

For reference, I'm running a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a brand new Lenovo Yoga C930, dual booted system. I ran

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

And received the output

```
6b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Some of the tools that I have access to: I have access to a separate machine with interwebs and I can transfer files via usb. I also have access to the internet via Windows 10, and I have heard that Ubuntu can read data files on an NTFS partition on Windows 10, but I have not been successful at figuring how to set this up or verify it.

I'm a similar level ubuntu practitioner to the question I am referencing, so please be gentle with me (and feel free to direct me to resources that can improve my literacy!)

Thank you all so much for your help!

Comment: You should check results for `rfkill list` and see if anything is blocked

Comment: There are no missing files that need to be downloaded. You already have a driver, namely *iwlwifi* and if it is not working as expected, it is almost certainly, as @Jeremy31 says, due to rfkill; that is, the wireless switch or key combination is set to disable (kill) the wireless radio.

Comment: Results for rfkill list:

`0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no`

Comment: so, after the comments above, I did some searching for Wireless Hard Blocked on Lenovo machines... entered BIOS through windows and the wireless is enabled there...still searching for solutions.

Comment: does `echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad-laptop.conf` make any change after a reboot

Comment: well, now my results for `rfkill list` are `0: phy0: Wireless LAN`
`Soft blocked: no   Hard blocked: no`

Comment: also: yes, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of user @Jeremy31

Solution:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad-laptop.conf"
```

and then reboot.

Results:

```
rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
```

Also, wireless now works. Very simple solution not requiring web access. Yay.