# Slow wireless on Lenovo C930 with iwlwifi driver

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, iwlwifi

I am trying to get my new installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Yoga C930 up and functional. My wireless has been giving me issues since the beginning. Currently my question is:

How do I fix a slow wireless connection on my machine?

Here is the history of what I've done so far:

1. The question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168028/follow-up-question-to-lenovo-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found) got my wireless from a Hard block to being unblocked.
2. Then, by following the advice given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168909/what-is-the-function-of-modprobe-in-this-code/1168973?noredirect=1#comment1950672_1168973), I was able to determine that I have a iwlwifi driver which needs to be modified to select a different wireless antenna.

So my more specific question is, how can I tell my machine to use the correct wireless antenna to get full signal and speed?

If the answer includes the `modprobe` or `modinfo` commands, that would be nice since I've been reading up on how to use them, but for a driver that was inapplicable to my setup.

Answer (score 1):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Comment: That's a lot of stuff I don't know how to do! How do I check the router settings?

Comment: I guess, while I'm clarifying, what's a fixed channel and how do I view/set it?

Comment: The router settings are found and changed by logging in to the administrative pages of the router. https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3325316/router_wireless_settings-channel.png

Comment: Cool. I don't know that I have access to those. Can I skip that step and try the next ones in your solution?

Comment: `sudo iw reg get` returns a lot of info. Inside it is a line: `phy#0: (self-managed)` `country US: DFS-UNSET` I am in the US. Does that mean I don't have to change anything here?

Comment: What does `cat /etc/default/crda` tell us? If it says: `REGDOMAIN=US` then you need make no change. If it says anything else, such as `REGDOMAIN=  ` then please change it.

Comment: It began as `REGDOMAIN=` and I have since updated it to `REGDOMAIN=US`. Performing a speedtest (Ookla) gave me 11mbps download and 1mpgs upload. I think that means my speed is back to normal. I have noticed no slowness, but my wireless signal shows only 2 bars even when I am sitting right next to the router. That leaves me as only 80% confident that I have solved my initial issue.

Comment: Are both antenna wires actually connected? https://media.karousell.com/media/photos/products/2019/02/04/intel_9260_173_gbps_245ghz_2x2_ac_bluetooth_50_1549261682_90828b630_progressive Both *Main* and *Aux* in the linked image.