# No wi-fi on new Ubuntu dual boot with Windows

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I have installed a new dual-boot with windows. I saw some error messages at first load, and had to disable some graphics to get the install wizard to run correctly. Ubuntu is all installed and beautiful, but is not showing Wi-Fi as an option. I can get internet via wired connection, but the OS is behaving as if my computer does not have a network adapter.

After doing some research on the command line I found that the adapter is the rtl8821ce, but cannot figure out any way to get Ubuntu to recognize and use it.

Comment: According to chilli, [this is the updated answer for newer versions of Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162258/167115).

Comment: Also, the newer answer uses DKMS so you won't have to manually re-install your driver every time there is a kernel update so I'd go with the updated answer unless you encounter issues.