# Could not found Wifi or switch?

Tags: wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 19.04 in my Lenovo ideapad along with windows 10 .

I could not found how to turn on WiFi even I could not get anything like " No WiFi adapter found " something like that.

Now it has passed a month and  I am getting frustrated with Ubuntu because I have to use internet by USB and some time my Phone also get over charged . My friend adviced me put result of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` which are

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: wl

And result of rfkill list all are 
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Actually I do not know what's going in above lines I am newbie and do not have any idea about Linux or ubuntu

Model Name : Lenovo ideaped 130-15lkb
Serial Number : MP1G5C7Y

Comment: Without knowing _which_ Lenovo Ideapad you have, don't know if there is a physical on/off switch or if there's a keystroke combination to turn WiFi off/on. On my ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 4,  F8 turns WiFi on/off, but since you have a different model, it's likely something else. Please look on the underside for the sticker with serial number and model number, get the model number from there, and click [edit] to add it into your question. Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)