# BIOS doesn't have secure boot?

Tags: boot, bios

So I am one of many that have trouble connecting to wi-fi after installing Ubuntu to dual boot with my Windows 10. I have followed everything in this guide, [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

and the only thing that is holding me back is not being able to disable secure boot. In my BIOS, there is nothing labeled "secure boot." I did fast boot but that didn't change anything, any recommendations?

This is the link to 5 pictures in each tab of my BIOS if anyone can tell me what I should disable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QHsl.jpg

Comment: Not necessarily, legacy and efi are supported, but efi is preferred.

Comment: Please tell us about *your* computer: Brand name and model. That will make it easier to give relevant help (particularly if someone here has a very similar computer).

Comment: Why do you think you have an RTL8821CE device?

Comment: If I understand you right, you compiled driver's kernel module but it doesn't work because of secure boot. You just have to sign it with `sbsign`. https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot

Answer (score 0):

UEFI capability does not necessarily imply secure boot capability.  Your machine has UEFI capability, but not secure boot.  It will boot either legacy or UEFI, but when both are possible, your priority is to boot the EFI first.

---

No secure boot capability means it cannot be enabled, so consider it disabled.

Comment: so if i am told to disable secure boot, what should i do?