# No WiFi or WiFi symbol

Tags: wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu when I went to connect WiFi there was not symbol in the top bar and couldn’t connect through settings I use a internal wireless driver.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` command:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek semiconductor co., Ltd. RTL 8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
        Subsystem Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth 
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Comment: Nope didn’t work

Comment: This means that you did something wrong. "didn't work" is not the information that allows to suggest anything.