# 19.10: WiFi install failure

Tags: command-line, dual-boot

When I run iwconfig, I see:

```
lo. no wireless extensions
enp2s0. no wireless extensions
```

What should I do? The Internet does not work, it is not even in the settings.

Ubuntu 19.10 is installed as a dual boot system added to Windows.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I'll do it now.

Comment: Lspci - https://ibb.co/mzQMzqd
Rfkill - https://ibb.co/nCVq9P5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Comment: Нет(,у него там в rfkill есть wifi а у меня нету(

Comment: This is the solution to install drivers for rtl8821ce.

Comment: how can i download drivers if i don't have internet?

Comment: You can connect using e.g. your phone through USB ;-)

Comment: But what to do when you installed the folder on the USB flash drive, transferred it to the desktop. how to install these drivers, a folder on your desktop

Comment: It is written there how to install. But I am afraid you can't intall it this way without the dependencies.

Comment: It is drivers : https://ibb.co/8mxX33H

Comment: As I said it won't work this way because you lack other things. There is another answer that automates this https://askubuntu.com/a/1071336/167850 but you need a n internet connection.

Comment: А как я загружу если у меня файфая на ноуте нету,можешь прислать инструкцию как сделать это с телефона?

Comment: And how will I download if I don’t have a file on the laptop, can you send instructions on how to do this from the phone?

Comment: You can connect your phone to USB port and have internet from there.

Comment: Fuxk,dont work ,USB cable dont enable

Comment: You need enable it in the phone.

Comment: I enabled it in the settings via usb

Comment: THANK YOUUUUU MANNNN,IT IS WORK!!!!!