# Asus VivoBook x543UB wifi driver propblem

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus

Ubuntu 19.10 installed to the new notebook. Wifi is not working even wifi adapter icon not displayed, only can see the bluetooth.
How can I fix this problem. The issue is more complicate since the notebook hasn't Ethernet port. Does anyone handled this issue?
Here is output from console:

```
azamat@vivoBook:~$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3;
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3040]
azamat@vivoBook:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
azamat@vivoBook:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: You can connect your phone using a USB cable to get temporary internet access.

Comment: @Pilot6 Associated link is really helped to fix the problem. Thank you! I just downloaded a zip file from github suggested here https://askubuntu.com/a/1071336/1049344 and transferred it by usb flash and run command sudo ./dkms-install.sh