# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless

I encountered this problem as well. In many cases I've seen that you must connect an internet cable to the laptop, install some drivers and you're done, but in my case, my laptop doesn't have a network cable input (ASUS X509FB). How can I solve this?

EDIT:

```
description: Wireless interface
                   product: ASUS_X018D
                   vendor: MediaTek
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: ff.ff
                   serial: HCAXJR19D032D9E
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rndis_host maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: USB2.0-CRW
                   vendor: Generic
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 39.60
--
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b4300000-b430ffff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.4
--   *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: ae:37:06:a1:dc:96
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.93 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: Use your phone as a USB modem.

Comment: I did it.......

Comment: If the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce please come back here and open a new question. Make sure to headline it "Realtek rtl8821ce WiFi fails in 18.04" , show us in detail what you did when following that answer, and include the results from _sudo lshw|grep -A15 'network\|Wireless'_

Answer (score 0):

Pages 24-25 of your manual https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X409FA/0409_E15108_X409_X509_A.pdf shows there's a USB-C port. If one came with the PC, please connect the [USB-C to Ethernet adapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB-C%20to%20Ethernet%20adapter) to that port and use that to connect to your wired network to get drivers.

Comment: There is no need to buy an adapter.