# How do you install .tar.xz files offline?

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I just installed Linux 20.04, and it didn't come with WiFi drivers and I can't get it online. I'm trying to install a program that has the .tar.xz file extension, and I was wondering how I would do so?

**Came with nothing pre-installed.**
**It's offline.**

**EDIT:**

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` responds with:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.RTL8821CE 802.11ac   
PCIe Wireless Network adapter [10ec:c821]  
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
```

And `rfkill list` responds with:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN soft blocked: no hard blocked: no 1:   ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth soft blocked: no hard blocked: no hci0: Bluetooth: soft blocked: no hard blocked: no
```

and nmcli device wifi list does nothing.

Comment: BTW, running the "Try Ubuntu" option on the USB key allows you to set these things up before you install, which then carries over to your install to save you the headache later. :-)

Comment: Okay, will do. @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh

Comment: RTL8821CE: See [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce). Complete instructions on what to download and how to install it are there. The larger hardware (ThinkPad E570) is irrelevant - only the WiFi chipset really matters.

Comment: Would this work without Ethernet? I don't have Ethernet at the time.

Comment: @user535733 that is way too confusing, and it seems outdated.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that your wireless hardware is not supported. That's Realtek's fault, not Ubuntu. Most wireless hardware IS supported and recognized out-of-the-box. We sympathize that yours isn't. The instructions may be confusing to a new user, sorry...but that's what folks told us that they must do to make RTL8821CE work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a few days I have finally received my Ethernet adapter. From there I installed the drivers from GitHub and finished it off by installing them.