# (Edited*) Ubuntu No Wifi EVEN AFTER installing realtek rtl8821ce wifi driver

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, connection, realtek

this is continued thread of
[Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi Option Non-existant (No GNOME, No option in settings)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250067/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-option-non-existant-no-gnome-no-option-in-settings?noredirect=1#comment2109374_1250067).

I followed instructions of [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce) as suggested by response. **However, there is still no Wifi connection. It stayed exactly same** (I disabled securemode in the BIOS setting)

***Thing about my laptop is that it doesn't even have WIFI as a Network option*** as demonstrated by three screenshots below. Most of others' problems relate to situation where 1) their wifi is too weak 2) Wifi is in questions mark 3) Wifi option is not in GNOME but at least exists in Settings toolbar.

In my case, It's in NOWHERE.
[image: Not in GNOME]
[image: Not in Settings]

**Edited section : screenshot of rekill command and lspci command**
[image: rfkill and lspci command]

**In addition, rfkill does not even list Network Controller but only lists Bluetooth as result (wifi definitely worked in windows)**
Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: I just edited post with screen shot of results of command you asked for. I hope it helps! Thanks!

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo modprobe 8821ce` and also: `dmesg | grep 8821`

Comment: for sudo modprobe 8821ce
[sudo] password for suho: 
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8821ce not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-37-generic

Comment: for dmesg | grep 8821
[    3.757765] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    3.758744] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    3.760483] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin

Comment: Did you follow @pHeLiOn 's answer as I suggested? Let's see: `sudo dkms status`