# No wireless option in settings menu for rtl8822ce

Tags: networking, drivers

I am new to ubuntu and have a laptop with a rtl8822ce wifi card.
I cannot see a wireless option in settings, but after plugging in an external wifi USB adapter the wireless option pops up in the settings menu.
there arent a lot of solutions to this query on this site.
please help me fix this and pardon me for my English.
is there something wrong with the rtl8822ce card?

edit 1: I'm using windows 10 and dual booted 20.04lts
result of uname -a gave me
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What OS & release are you using.  You only mention bing *new to Ubuntu* without telling us what OS & release you have installed.

Comment: Please edit your question & include the output of `uname  -a`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)