# Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo IdeaPad330S (Realtek RTL8821CE)

Tags: drivers, wireless, software-installation

My computer does not have a ethernet port so how can I go about updating the driver. Would I just download the things to USB and then run commands? Are there any steps I can take to get this working? I am new to Linux so any guidance would be appreciated. Sorry for the picture but that laptop is not able to connect to the internet at the moment. What command would be helpful to show for troubleshooting?

Comment: We don't know your OS or release, which is a starting point. Also text is much easier to read than a picture of text (yes you can copy the text via USB thumb-drive).

Comment: Is there a certain command that would help you troubleshoot? Then I will copy it to notepad and repost the results to be able to read.

Comment: Knowing what OS & release you are using is the first step. For non-LTS releases, it tells us the kernel you are using, for LTS release as there are two kernel options, we narrow it down to two unless you're specific as to what you installed (ie. the .point release). Drivers is the user-friendly term for a *kernel modules* thus the importance of what OS you're using, and especially the kernel information the OS provides.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce

Comment: kernel = driver thanks never knew that. Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS .

Comment: *kernel module* = *driver*.   It's the software that allows the kernel to speak (through the kernel module) to specific hardware.  Same applies in other OSes (inc. windows), it just that everyone calls them *drivers* (user term, rather than the technical term).  Ubuntu 20.04.2 tells me you're using the 5.8 kernel for example (assuming desktop, if it was Ubuntu 20.04.2 Server it would be 5.4 kernel but you have the option at install to use 5.8 instead).  The extra .0 was because of a OEM flaw; which caused re-spin.