# How do I make my network card show up?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

New Linux user here. Just started using it to gain experience. I made it so I can dual boot windows and Ubuntu. Windows recognises my network card and uses it, but Linux does not have the required drivers for it. I have no way of making a wired Internet connection.
The lshw command shows me an "UNCLAIMED" network controller.
It says it's an "RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter"
So what do I do here?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.10 by the way.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce will get you there :)

Comment: Did I forget to mention I do not have access to a wired connection? @Rinzwind ?

Comment: You may need to boot into windows to download the required driver, and then transfer it to Ubuntu

Comment: @VictorRijnoveanu you do not need one to install software. a usb is enough