# Problem With Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 AC PCIE adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I am using an HP M01-F0xxx desktop with a Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 AC PCIE adapter running Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to access the WiFi settings I get a message saying "No WiFi adapter found" in the settings menu. I go into the **Additional Drivers** section of the **Software & Updates** app and see this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJGnf.png)).

Not sure what to do. I run lspci -v and this comes up for my wireless adapter

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter:
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Memory at fcc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

I've tried disabling secure boot and rebooting my PC but this did nothing. Anyone have any ideas? I ran commands `sudo dkms status`, `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl` and `rfkill list all` and these are the results:

```
username@username-HP-Desktop-M01-F0xxx:~$ sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for username: 
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1: added
username@username-HP-Desktop-M01-F0xxx:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl
[    1.678357] r8169 0000:0a:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 00:68:eb:9a:54:d1, XID 541, IRQ 47
[    5.211204] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
[    5.214487] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.214490] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
[    5.216227] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
[    5.216474] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 10, total sz 31990
[    6.307374] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x829a7644
username@username-HP-Desktop-M01-F0xxx:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I've attempted to download the drivers using the instructions on [this](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3_all.deb.html) page but I got a few error messages during the download:

```
username@username-HP-Desktop-M01-F0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                  
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]                                  
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                     
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 15min 31s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 45min 19s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 2h 16min 17s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
username@username-HP-Desktop-M01-F0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rtl8821ce-dkms is already the newest version (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing old rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.5.2.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-43-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-43-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8821ce-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi not working on Lenovo ThinkPad E570 (Realtek RTL8821CE)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl` and finally: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 just updated the post!

Comment: You need to have Secure Boot disabled and install rtl8821ce-dkms

Comment: @Jeremy31 just updated the post with the results from the download.

Comment: Please see: "Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information." The driver package did not compile and install correctly. Let's see what the log message is: `cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/T7JwrTc2rs/

Comment: You also have a MAJOR time desync on your system, I would suggest using an NTP server to update your time (because it says that 'security repositories' aren't valid yet in your system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that the slightly newer version of this driver includes, in the Changelog:

> - Fix build against v5.8 kernel (LP: #1884648)

Let's try to install it instead. With a working internet connection:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1 --all
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8821ce/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i rtl8821*.deb
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Yes! Awesome man I really appreciate that. Linux noob here haha. The problem seems to be fixed!