# wifi issues in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 23.10

I installed ubuntu 23.10. My wifi suddenly disconnects then again reconnects and this cycle goes on. It shows activation of connection failed

```
$ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 30:24:a9:3a:2f:46
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-25-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:50504000-50504fff memory:50500000-50503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 5c:ba:ef:7d:2e:bf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=6.5.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip= latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:50400000-5040ffff
```

```
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2216] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2219] device (wlo1): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2404] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2406] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2406] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Feb 12 12:20:37 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720637.2407] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 12 12:20:52 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720652.9668] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0166] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0171] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <warn>  [1707720683.0177] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'SAMBIT'
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0184] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0204] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0204] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.0204] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.2053] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Feb 12 12:21:23 sambit-HP-Laptop-15-da3xxx NetworkManager[1016]: <info>  [1707720683.6783] policy: auto-activating connection 'SAMBIT' (6e6dcaaf-57cc-49ce-b17b-2c558c2394d8)
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tWrzjyV9Dx/

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jWnF57GzNs/

please tell if u need output from any command.

Comment: Does [this question "Problem With Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 AC PCIE adapter"](https://askubuntu.com/q/1330991/51957) help you? It is somewhat old, but maybe the problem is similar.

Comment: Please [edit] with https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1004020 . Also add any lines from `dmesg` and `journalctl -r` that got logged near the time of the problem

Comment: done. i have edited the question.