# Ubuntu keep disconnecting me from 5 in 5 min from any network

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

I keep getting disconnected (network drops) and when this happen i still see that i am connected to the network there is and its not looking like its loading or something. I tested this with hotspot connection with my phone and still the same. I tried do reinstall the system and still the same thing. This is not my router problem. I tried a lot of tutorials of how to repair this problem and no one worked. My specs:

```
wlp4s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet "my ip"  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast "my ip"
        inet6 fe80::e57d:f0fe:512a:8cf9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether e8:fb:1c:49:e5:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 186777  bytes 177394314 (177.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 119555  bytes 57533455 (57.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 16
       serial: 84:69:93:59:17:88
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.5.0-17-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:55 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: e8:fb:1c:49:e5:81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.5.0-17-generic firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.0.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:7f0-7ef iomemory:7f0-7ef iomemory:7f0-7ef irq:91 memory:7f20300000-7f203fffff memory:7f20400000-7f20403fff memory:7f20404000-7f20404fff
```

this is my laptop: HP OMEN by HP Gaming Laptop 16-n0xxx

my version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

I no more don't know what to do i even installed another linux and i found out that its not my wifi card problem and its the system or the driver.

i have found this post but its old and no more can install the git: [Problem With Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11 AC PCIE adapter](https://askubuntu.com/q/1330991/51957)

EDIT:

```
iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"MyWifiName"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: 50:91:E3:5C:1C:DC
Bit Rate=585 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

Comment: Please edit to include results for `iwconfig; cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubuntu 22.04 - wifi freeze after hwe kernel upgrade to 6.5 (was fine on 6.2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499938/kubuntu-22-04-wifi-freeze-after-hwe-kernel-upgrade-to-6-5-was-fine-on-6-2)

Answer (score 0):

I bet it will work better with power management off

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
sudo iwconfig wlp4s0 power off
```

Comment: Now when i am using firefox and opening tabs of pages i get disconnected form the internet and i can see that by having the ping google.com command in the background. And when i am gaming it no more disconnect me.

Comment: What part of that question solved it?

Comment: when i am gaming it no more disconnecting me but when i use firefox i get disconnected ...