# Fresh installation of 20.04 LTS doesn't display WiFi in top right menu

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, wireless

[Picture of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjTlb.png)

I freshly installed ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Yoga539 14ARR laptop. The WiFi option doesn't appear either on the top right menu or the settings.

After some web searching I have used the '''sudo lshw -C network''' command and have gotten the results in the picture.

My best understanding is that there is some issue with the drivers, but I'd really appreciate a few thoughts from people that are more savvy than me.

What is the cause here and how do I go about solving it? I will gladly provide any more info you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Ask Ubuntu.
WiFi

Out of the box, Ubuntu won't see the built in WiFi adapter (which happens to be RealTek RTL8821CE).
BIOS

Go to bios and turn off SecureBoot. It tends to turn it on again after BIOS upgrades.
Blacklist

Popular solution is to blacklist ideapad_laptop kernel module (like mentioned at this Lenovo forum thread https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Yoga-920-How-to-run-Linux/td-p/3895778), like this:
`echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_ideapad.conf`  
However it did not enable WiFi for me. (Though I am not certain it was not helpful together with the next point.)

What helped was this:

```
echo "blacklist 8821ce" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

See also this link:https://dev.to/anatolyscherbakov/running-ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-530-transformer-laptop-4c7m  for more info/behaviour issues.
Hope it solves your problem and if if does please accept the answer by clicking on the V-shaped icon next to the answer.

Comment: So what you did was downloading and intalling the needed drivers and kernels? If so my problem is that I only can connect to the internet via other PCs and need to download manually all of the depentences, right?

Comment: Blacklist the normal ideapad configuration in the kernel and download the driver manual. How would you connect to another computer? You can also download the driver to a usb stick on another computer and then install it on the Lenovo.

Comment: ok, so is this a problem with ubuntu only? Cause if other linux distributions are ok then I'm fine with just moving ti mint or something else. Would they also have this or not?

Comment: I don't know. Try it in a live environment. I'm not even sure what causes this problem. I also don't know if you install another kernel ( not Ubuntu, but a mainline kernel ) this problem will be there.