# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found after install ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Thinkbook 2022 14+

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

No Wi-Fi Adapter Found after install ubuntu 22.04 LTS for Thinkbook 14+, cpu 12th alder lake 12700H

I tried `sudo lshw -c network`

It shows

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network Controller
    product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pic@0000:2c:00.0
    version:00
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resouces: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:5e300000-5e3fffff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Ethernet Connection (16) I219-V
......
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get update`,

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

and edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, change `managed=true`

It still failed.

I tried `lspci -nnk | grep Net`; `rfkill list`;
and It shows below:

```
aaa@aaa-14-2022:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
2c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
2d:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [17aa:386b]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question of https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce.

Comment: Please specify your hardware better. There are many Thinkpad 14's. E, L, T, T14s, Gen 2, Gen 10

Comment: Lenovo ThinkBook 14 G4+, i7-12700H, 16G, 512G, Wi-Fi 6.

Comment: w@3w-14-2022:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
2c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
2d:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1217:8621] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [17aa:386b]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no